# Does adding a method to a sub-class with the same name of the parent class method, break substitutability principle?

Tags: object-oriented, solid, liskov-substitution

Let `T` be a superclass, and `S` derives from it:

```
abstract class T{
public virtual byte[] Foo(string str){...}
}

class S : T{
public override byte[] Foo(string str){....}
public byte[] Foo(string str, bool b){...}
}
```

As per the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), if:

```
S s = new S();
var data = s.Foo("dt", false);
```

I should be able to substitute `S` with `T`:

```
T t = new S();

var data = t.Foo("dt", false); //can't call this.
```

Does this design break LSP?

Should I, in this case, change the name of the method in the derived class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should be able to substitute `S` with `T`

No. You should be able to substitute `T` with `S`.

> Does this design break LSP?

No, it doesn't. Any client that only knows about `T` will not even now that the second overload exists, so it will never try to call it, and thus there will be no change in behavior.